# package.json not found when moving from Dockerfile to docker-compose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting to know React and created a small application using `Create-React-App`, which is run inside a docker container using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install -g react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

#add app to container
COPY . ./
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

That works fairly well and I now wanted to integrate this into a docker-compose workflow, to run an api backend using asp.net core and this React application side-by-side:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  backend:
    asp.netcore
  db:
    sql2019linux
  ui:
    container_name: ui
    build:
      context: ./UI
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
```

This now fails with the node error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The backend and db services are coming up finde. What exactly is going sideways here and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be your problem.

```
volumes:
  - './:/app'
```

Looks like you are mounting the directory that the `docker-compose` files is in to the app directory of the container and `npm start` is probably bawking because it cannot find the `package.json` in the `workdir` of the built image (which is also `/app`).

Try removing the volumes.

Comment: suppose I want to keep those volumes, so changes to the source files, do get picked up and it can hot-reload.

Comment: Use a different docker file. One that just has your runtime in it i.e. node:latest and doesn't rebuild your code, just runs your app. I would suggest that there are probably better alternatives than doing that though. If your use case is to make changes to your code. I would run my app locally and expose any dependencies / services from my compose file. If your app code is in the UI directory, you would prob have to mount `./UI:/app`

Comment: Changing the workdir to `/usr/src/app` and then mapping the volume to `./usr/src/app:/app` does the trick, but the hot-reloading does not yet work.

Comment: Not sure if you are using some lib or other black magic for hot reloading - but once a process is stopped in the container, the container is done. You will have to restart the container / service

Comment: The `create-react-app` does it ootb - I am just at the beginning of my journey and haven't looked under the hood too closely yet, so I can't give you a def. answer on that one.